# I'm adding data into array but, it's end up with only the last item in the array. It seems to overwrite

Tags: django

```
request.session['list'] = []
if request.method =='POST':    
  newrecord = request.POST['market']
  tmp = request.session['list']
  tmp.append(newrecord)
  request.session['market_list'] = tmp
```

I turn out that previous data was overwrite by the new one

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an empty list to `request.session['list']` in the first line of the code snippet you have given. Is this by design? In that case it is no surprise that `tmp` always ends up with one element only.

Answer (score 0):

change `request.session['list'] = []` to

```
if not request.session.has_key('list'):     
  request.session['list'] = []
```